# img loses center position after hiding and unhiding div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that hides and unhides a div element on button click and it works fine. The issue is once the div is hidden then unhidden the IMG loses its center position. I don't know what is causing this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function hide_unhide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cont1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#cont1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont1">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/96/000000/stackoverflow.png" />
</div>

<button onclick="hide_unhide()">toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple mistake. You need to change it to flex, not block.

```
function hide_unhide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cont1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```